# What handy protein source before going to bed after training day?

Tags: bodybuilding

Chicken requires cooking, I hate tuna or stuff like that. Any easy alternative for steady protein supply during sleep after a training day?

Comment: This is basically asking "What do you like", which isn't on topic on most SE sites. Additionally, we expect nutrition questions related to the workout in some fashion other than "I work out I need protein".

Comment: I'd recommend 200-300 grams of low-fat curd(or quark, in russia we got "tvorog", little different taste than in western countries but still). I usually use some sweetener + hot water and then put curd in it, so it gonna taste fine

Comment: Canned chicken avoids the cooking problem

Comment: Thanks Danil Gholtsman I'll totally do that! Thanks ford prefect too, I might give it a try too.